# Program to quicly remove specks from images

Tags: images, image-processing, image-editor

I need a program to quicly remove speckes (dust) from images (manually). At the moment I use XnView: I open an image (standard ones: jpg,tiff, and png), select a speck and press the delete button. To go to another picture I press right key. I'd like to have a freeprogram on Windows 7 which allows me to remove a speck by using a brush or by selecting a speck (without pressing del button).

Comment: Did you ever get a solution? If so, please let us know, as it would help others, juts like we try to help you. Did you try Stephen's suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (GNU Image Manipulation Program). Specifically, you might try the GIMP [Despeckle plugin](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-despeckle.html).